# Converting timezone for date faster using java 

Tags: java, date, timezone, timestamp

I have written this method for converting a date time zone. How do i reduce the execution time of this method further.

```java
public static Timestamp convertTimeZone(final Timestamp fromDate, final TimeZone fromTZ, final TimeZone toTZ ){
   Long timeInDate  =  fromDate.getTime() ;
   int fromOffset = fromTZ.getOffset(timeInDate);
   int toOffset = toTZ.getOffset(timeInDate);
   Timestamp dateStamp = new Timestamp(fromDate.getTime());

   if (fromOffset >= 0){
      int diff = 0;

      if (toOffset > 0){
          diff = (fromOffset - toOffset);
      } else {
          diff = (fromOffset + Math.abs(toOffset));
      }

      long date = fromDate.getTime() - diff;
      dateStamp.setTime(date);
   } else {
      int diff = 0;

      if (toOffset > 0){
          diff = (Math.abs( fromOffset) + toOffset);
      } else {
          diff = (Math.abs( fromOffset) - Math.abs(toOffset));
      }

      long date = fromDate.getTime() + diff;
      dateStamp.setTime(date);
   }

   return dateStamp;
}
```

Comment: It is O(1), what do you mean 'execution time' ?

Comment: This should really be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com not here.

Comment: I need to improve the time taken to convert the timezone.

Comment: I won't get any timezone information from mysql on retrieving.so converting manually.

Answer (score 2):

With [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) it may look like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
System.out.println(dt); // 5 am
dt = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("EET"));
System.out.println(dt); // 8 am
```

Note that `Timestamp` has no notion of Timezone so it is not suitable for representing it.

Your solution will have a good running time, since it's O(1). It's harder to read though.

Comment: +1 for introducing joda-time (not that you need any more points)

Comment: The code got cut off.  Can you add the rest?  You could also mention the concept of `LocalDate` as it might help the OP.  I always feel bad when I see programmers stuck with plain ol' Java dates and calendars and timestamps.

Comment: sorry, that was redundant line. As I noted on the next line - you can't get good tz representation in Timestamp (unless you set a different date, as the OP is doing, which is not entirely good)

Comment: Yes, there is a problem in tz representation which i am not interested, what i need is a faster implementation

Answer (score 1):

You could store your date in a Calendar object to begin with. Showing it in different time zone formats will be a matter of configuration that you apply to a SimpleDateFormat.

Technically a Date is the same in all time zones (it's internal value is the same). Applying the concept of timezones allows date formatters to adjust offsets for display. In other words, a Date that represents 17:00 in London time is equal to a Date that represents 12:00 in New York. Displaying it in the GMT vs. the EST time zones can be a function of date formatters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite an answer, but I recommend always store timestamp in database as UTC time instead of local time. And display it for different timezones only on presentation layer setting `DateFormat.setTimeZone()`