# How to convert UTC time in millis to formatted date-time in different time zones using joda time?

Tags: java, jodatime

What is the best way to render a UTC time in millis to a formatted time depending on the time zone (using joda time)?

**Example:**

If I have the `currrentTimeInGMT = 1322137038601`.
How can I convert this time to the format `'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss'` with date-time differing according to the time zone?

Comment: Why do you want to use Joda instead of the standard API for this?

Comment: If you're doing anything but the most trivial date/time stuff, you should use Joda Time - it's a breath of fresh air after standard JDK APIs, which rank as some of the worst in the JDK.

Comment: Joda is perhaps a breath of fresh air, but also lacks some rather trivial functionality and has IMHO (at least partially) a rather unintuitive API. Nevertheless, that was not my question. I asked Emil why he wants to use Joda for exactly this task: formatting a timestamp with a conditional time zone.

Comment: @jarnbjo: I'm currently using the standard api for this.I just wanted to benchmark and see if Joda time give's a better performance.For the current implementation you can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771699/converting-timezone-for-date-faster-using-java) .If you can give a better implementation i would like to see it.

Comment: The implementation you are linking to is not very clever. It is already mentioned in the responses that you shouldn't manipulate Date or Timestamp instances to apply timezone information, since these classes have no knowledge of time zone.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Then how to do this using the standard api ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following to create a `DateTime` from milliseconds and give it a specific timezone:

```
DateTime d =
  new DateTime(1322137038601L).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
```

To do the custom formatting:

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss").print(d));
```